# Why there is no all_or_nothing support in Cloudant?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I tried to make an atomic bulk documents update with `all_or_nothing` set to `true` on Cloudant, but got the following response:

```
    [{"id":"7b75974f73c4230047b96b5272b696fd","rev":"1-e9b78ecba4c4ac29a9743cd001219eae","error":"not_implemented","reason":"all_or_nothing is not supported yet"},
    {"id":"921faa913230839614a4feb19d5c39ec","rev":"0-","error":"not_implemented","reason":"all_or_nothing is not supported yet"}]
```

I followed [CouchDB documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/bulk-api.html#api-db-bulk-docs-semantics) because Cloudant is a fork of CouchDB and for most uses it seems to be compatible. Not in this case.

So I looked into [Cloudant documentation](https://docs.cloudant.com/api.html#bulk-operations) and indeed the `all_or_nothing` flag is not mentioned there at all. It is not mentioned in [Moving Apache CouchDB Data
to Cloudant](https://cloudant.com/wp-content/uploads/CouchDB-to-Cloudant.pdf) white paper either.

Now I wonder.. **is it by design** (maybe it shouldn't be needed if data is modeled the proper NoSQL way? Are there any best practices that apply here?) or is it **just a missing feature**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `all_or_nothing` flag is not supported on Cloudant. It was removed when CouchDB was forked and became BigCouch. As the databases is sharded and stored on separate machines, it would be be overcomplicated to provide `all_or_nothing` guarantees in a distributed system, where your _bulk_docs requests ends up writing to separate shards.

I wouldn't be surprised to find that this is removed from the forthcoming CouchDB 2.0 aswell.

Comment: Thanks, I read this as "it's by design". Could you please provide some links to documentation or other Cloudant resources that would back up that statement or it is just your opinion? I created this question because it was so hard to find anything on that topic, so any links are appreciated.