# How to insert a model with DoctrineCouchDBBundle and SF 2.8?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, couchdb-2.0

I've a fresh install of Symfony 2.8 and [DoctrineCouchDBBundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCouchDBBundle). I've created a minimal model to try to insert an object into CouchDB, but I have the following error :

```
HTTP Error with status 417 occurred while requesting /symfony/_bulk_docs. Error: not_implemented all_or_nothing is not supported
```

I read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554887/why-there-is-no-all-or-nothing-support-in-cloudant) that **all_or_nothing** could be removed in CouchDB 2.0, is it done ? I am using CouchDB 2.0 and I would use Doctrine with Couchdb 2.0.
Is it a Doctrine problem, or a DoctrineCouchDBBundle problem that is not up to date with the last Doctrine version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by turning off all_or_nothing while using CouchDB 2.0

My config.yml looks like this now:

```
doctrine_couch_db:
  client:
    dbname: symfony
  odm:
     document_managers:
      default:
        all_or_nothing_flush: false
        auto_mapping: true
```

Comment: Where did you find this *all_or_nothing_flush* configuraton ? I didn't find it.. I'll test it now !
And since you are the first to finally answer, thank you !

Comment: I tested it, with this option everything looks right! Thank you. But I didn't found a complete documentation about it.

Comment: The link to the documentation on the repo's README is wrong, but the given option can be found by running the following command:
`php app/console config:dump-reference doctrine_couch_db`

Comment: I found the config-option in the command php app/console config:dump-reference doctrine_couch_db, also I looked in all the files in the bundle to figure out why it was not working. The only docs I found for the couchdb doctrine stuff was http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-couchdb/index.html