# How do we use CouchDB's _bulk_docs with all_or_nothing option?

Tags: transactions, couchdb, pouchdb

In the [CouchDB documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API) they say we can insert documents in bulk, with `all_or_nothing` or `new_edits` option if we want to. But it seems, `all_or_nothing` key does not have any effects when we use like so:

```
HOST="http://test:test@localhost:5984/mydb"

curl -vX POST "$HOST/_bulk_docs" \
    -H "Content-type: application/json" \
    -d @test.json
```

with a test.json:

```
{
    "all_or_nothing":true,
    "docs":[
        {"_id":"hello"},
        {"_id":"world"}
    ]
}
```

This inserts documents which have `hello` and `world` ids. Re-running the script by replacing `hello` with `hello1` should cause `hello1` to be inserted in the database but fail the `world` document's recording (since it doesn't have correct `_rev`), thus they both SHOULD fail because we said `all_or_nothing`. But in the end, there are 3 documents in the database: `hello`, `hello1` and `world`.

How do we use `all_or_nothing` with CouchDB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My usage was correct. However, there are more than one reason why my attempts are failed:

1. PouchDB-server simply ignores (even without a proper error) `all_or_nothing` as they [do believe](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/1013) this is the correct way.
2. Cloudant simply [drops this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554887/why-there-is-no-all-or-nothing-support-in-cloudant) as they keep their database service distributed and transaction thing does not let the database scale.
3. CouchDB [dropped `all_or_nothing` support in 2.0 version](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2.0.html#upgrade-notes).